# Is there a plug-in sample for Firefox 5 written in C++?

Tags: c++, firefox-addon, gecko, firefox-5

I've seen several examples, but for libraries with Gecko 1.9.2 or earlier, how do I create a plugin for Firefox 5 in C++?

The strange thing is that the official website just to gives me examples for Firefox v. 1.5 through v. 3.6 which is why I have experienced some difficulty.

Comment: I will warn you now go the javascript route. The build process for a c++ plugin is a nightmare and will ONLY work with the version that it is compiled against. (At least major version). But this is also my opinion so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: the problem is I have a library in C and I have to use

Comment: I would give you a pat on the back and a cookie if I could right now.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using [ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes).